# Controlling character movement, and keeping score while doing so, AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, scoring

I have created a game where you have to follow the suggested arrow (going from right to left) to control the movement of the character. As you go trace the arrow from right to left, the characters position changes and he rubs his forehead. I wanted it to be very interactive, so you feel like you are controlling the character. As he rub his forehead, I want the "heat meter" to increase, and after it reaches hot, the level is completed. Is this even possible with Actionscript 3?  Thank you in advance for letting me know, and if it is, how would I go about setting this up. I am very new to AS3. :/

Comment: http://duckiedeck.com/play/tooth-brushing#.UXmSMLWcdqU   <_----- The way that you have to run over the teeth to get them clean is what I want in actionscript.

Comment: Or would it be easier to change it to where they have to hold down the mouse while rubbing his head like this : http://www.primarygames.com/science/brilliantbrushers/index.htm

Comment: Both those games are actionscript based. Doesn't that answer your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `gotoAndStop()` to navigate to the head scratching menu using if statements (`if(var thinking:Boolean == true)` and to the heat meter: `if(character.currentFrame == "scratchinghead") { var heatmeter:int ++; }`

Then to win: `if(heatmeter > 99) { gotoAndStop("win"); }`

To check if the mouse is hovering, use `MOUSE_ROLL_OVER`.

Comment: and that would work even if the you hover over the arrow to make the movements? Because as you move across the arrow, they are button instances where in the hover state, they show the next arm movement.

Comment: For hover you could use MOUSE_ROLL_OVER events

Comment: Your welcome.  In flash, don't ask what kind of games you can make; you can make every game you think of, from a 2d sidescroller to a 3d first person shooter.  You can even do more things with ANEs, or Native Extentions.

Comment: Thank you all for the help! I get so stuck on one thing, that I can not look past anything else and it messes me up.